# Core data with to-many relationship/

Tags: iphone, core-data

I am using core data. I am having 2 Entities Music and Lyrics .I created relationship musicTolyrics with inverse and To-many. I have to  save number of timestamps and lyrics for one song. I m using this code

```
Lyrics *lyrics = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Lyrics" 
   inManagedObjectContext:context];

lyrics.Lyrics = albumTitleField.text;
lyrics.startTime = 0.0;

lyrics.lyricsTomusic = music;
```

This is saving this in coredata. but I want to save number of records for 1 song..just like Foreign key.. How can I do this ? please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your inverse is the wrong way. Rather than "Music" which is quite ambiguous, let's call it "Song". So, a `Song` has "Lyrics". Other Songs could also use the same `Lyrics`.

So far then, we have a many-to-one relationship in that Many Songs can use the same Lyrics.

What I'd recommend is that you map this out in the Core Data modeller. Then, generate the class files automatically. You'll then see that in the to-many relationship, you can add an object to a set, so you'll have for example:

```
Song *mySong =  [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Song"     
innManagedObjectContext:context];

Lyrics *myLyrics =  [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Lyrics"     
innManagedObjectContext:context];
```

That's the two objects in Core Data. Now to define the relationship with the inverse:

```
Song.lyrics = myLyrics;
[myLyrics addSongObject:mySong];
```

If you set things up correctly in the model, you'll see that method `addSongObject` generated for you automatically.

Comment: If you have it modeled correctly, you don't even need to add the `mySong` object to `myLyrics`. Setting the lyrics on `Song` will handle the inverse relationship automatically.

Comment: No.. I want relationship like songs may have number of time stamps with lyrics.. no lyrics can be shared for more than one song

Comment: ah, ok. What does the timestamp represent? Is it the length of the song, or a point within the song?